# C# Get previous input with arrow up key

Tags: c#, list, keydown

Okai, let's say we have:

- 2 Textboxes (textBox1, textBox2)
- 1 Button (button1)
- A List (list1)

What I'm trying to do is to store the text that has been entered in textBox1 to list1 so I can easily retrieve my previous input. The text from textBox1 will be written to list1 when I press the button. this is the code that I have so far:

```
    private static List<string> list1 = new List<string>();

    list1.Add(textBox1.Text); // <-- On the button click event.

private void ServerInputtextboxCommand_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                foreach (var usedCommand in list1)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = usedCommand;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

So I'm trying to get the text I've entered in textBox1 back to textBox1 with the arrow up key.
The text I enter in textBox1 will be shown in textBox2 (but this isn't relevant here).

Thanks for all who want to help me, because I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(.

Comment: your foreach loop will result in always the last usedCommand to be assigned to your TextBox1

Comment: How am I able to get let's say, the second item in the list?

Comment: Do you mean you want to cycle between perviously entered commands?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a `Stack<T>` - it will be easier to track.

You can then use something like this:

```
public Stack<string> Undo { get; set; } // needs to be initialized before use
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                return;

            Undo.Push(textBox1.Text);
}

private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Up)
                return;

            if (Undo.Count == 0)
                return;

            textBox2.Text = Undo.Pop();
}
```

if you want a redo option then you can have a redo stack as well.

Comment: Maybe a noob question, but why is a stack better than a list in this case?

Comment: stack is a Last in first out data type. so it will stack your inputs as you enter them and pop them in reverse. You can read more here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx

Comment: Alright, looks much better than a list indeed. Thanks, I'm going to try this too. Just finding the best way to accomplish this :)!

Comment: I dont think this is gona work very well. If you pop the strings out of stack, the next time user enters something in textbox, the stack will be reset. yea?! correct me if I am wrong :P

Comment: @Sean87: yes it is a one time undo operation and not circular. That is how i understood the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a good start. So we are talking win forms right?

Do you want this functionality to only work when the text box is selected?

I assume you want functionality a bit like windows command line terminal where you press up and it brings back previous commands, one at a time. Your foreach loop looks like it will write/ over write all previous contents of the text box. I assume this is NOT what you want.

I suggest maintaining an index for your list that idicates which element is currently active in the text box. Then each time the user presses the up button, increment that index so that the next time the up button is pressed your system knows the index of the next element. I don't think you need a loop at all here if my assumtions are correct.

updated:
pseudo code:

```
int index = -1;
list listy = new listy;

onButtonClick{
-add current contents to list at index + 1
}

onKEYPress{
if(listy.get(index +1 ) is not null or empty)
{
-textbox.text = listy.get(index +1 )
++ index;
}
}
```

Comment: Man, did you read my mind? This is exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: let me know if you need more clarification